# How to rotate text on table with two rowspan using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

ok, i've been trying hours to make my HTML code working for rotating text on my table, but doesnt seem to work.

here is jsfiddle, if anyone is willing to help me, I will appreciate that

https://jsfiddle.net/zmxr9kyh/

here my html code

```js
$(function() {
  var header_height = 0;
  $('table th span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() > header_height) header_height = $(this).outerWidth();
  });

  $('table th').height(header_height);
});
```

```css
th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
th span {
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-table;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 100;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: -110;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" align="center" border='1'>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>

      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">

      </th>
      <th colspan="12" align="center">
        <center>VALIDASI</center>
      </th>
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">
        <center></center>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" align="center">
        <center>JUMLAH RECORD</center>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">NO.</th>
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">PROGRAM STUDI</th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>IDENTITAS MAHASISWA</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>MAHASISWA PT</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>KURIKULUM</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>NILAI</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>AKM</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2"><span>DAYA TAMPUNG</span>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>%</center>
      </th>
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF"><span>LAPORAN %</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="3" align="center">
        <center>MHS</center>
      </th>
      <th style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF">
        <center>
          KELAS KKULIAH
        </center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>NILAI</center>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="2">
        <center>AKM</center>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>
        <center></center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>A</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>C</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>N</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center></center>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writing-mode` is your friend:

```
th span {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

You might have to add vendor prefixes.

- [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmxr9kyh/2/)
- [More information](https://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css)
- [Browser support of `writing-mode`](http://caniuse.com/#search=writing-mode)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Jsfiddle seems work, but when I applied to my code it doesn't. The result shown like this http://imgur.com/a/xDX9d . I have other table above this table. Maybe it's the cause ??

Comment: Please check again if you've removed the CSS and JS that I've removed in the JSFiddle. You don't need any JS for this and also `th span` shouldn't be absolutely positioned.

Comment: wow it's work, with removing margin-bottom:-110; and width:100; Thanks for your magic